# I have a problem with php, the query.php page does not receive the POST request sent from index.php from the form

Tags: php, html, post

I have a problem with php, the query.php page does not receive the POST request sent from index.php from the form

query.php

```
$data = $_POST;
$type = "cha";
echo var_dump($data);
echo $type;
```

index.php

```
    <form action="query.php" method="POST" id="sendFrom">
    <div class="conteiner post">
        <select name="Type" id="select1" onchange="select1Change()">
            <option value="change">Type</option>
            <?php $query = mysqli_query($link, "select * from transport_type");
            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
                <option value='<?php echo $result['ID'] ?>;<?php echo $result['Type'] ?>'><?php echo $result['Type'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <select name="Type2" id="select2">
            <option value="change" dissabled>Car type</option>
            <?php $query = mysqli_query($link, "select * from transport_type2");
            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
                <option value='<?php echo $result['ID'] ?>;<?php echo $result['Type2'] ?>'><?php echo $result['Type2'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <select name="Brand" id="select3">
            <option value="change">Brand</option>
            <?php $query = mysqli_query($link, "select * from transport_brand");
                while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
                    <option value='<?php echo $result['ID'] ?>;<?php echo $result['Brand'] ?>'><?php echo $result['Brand'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="MinPeriod" id="text1">
        <select name="Unit" id="select4">
            <option value="change">Unit</option>
            <?php $query = mysqli_query($link, "select * from transport_period_unit");
                while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
                    <option value='<?php echo $result['ID'] ?>;<?php echo $result['Unit'] ?>'><?php echo $result['Unit'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="Price" id="text2">
        <input type="text" name="Comment" id="text3">
                <button id="inputSubmit" type="submit">Create</button>
                </form>
```

And thats what i get on query.php

[image: thats what i get]

I don't know what to do

Comment: your button does not have the type submit : `<button id="inputSubmit" type="submit">Create</button>`

Comment: the same issue (

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a [mre] of the issue if I'm honest. It doesn't appear to be possible to get that result, based on the code shown

Comment: Have you tried this ?
    `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    }`

Comment: yes i tried, and on your code i get this stderr: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "REQUEST_METHOD"

Comment: Are you somehow running that from the command line PHP instead of the webserver? Otherwise I don't think it makes sense that the array key would be missing. Yet your screenshot appears to show a browser session. It's all very odd and something doesn't add up, I feel like you're not mentioning something that would be significant, but I can't think what it would be.

Comment: `dissabled` is a typo